# Implementing a .Net web forms spell checker

Tags: .net, webforms, tinymce, spell-checking, rte

I'm implementing a .net web forms spell checker in one of our applications.
This application is only run internally and the clients do not have access to the internet so I cannot use an online spell checker like google's.

I came across many posts on SO that advocate using NetSpell. However I've been unable to figure out how to hook it up to a text editor like tiny mce.

Is there an example somewhere that I can follow?
Is there an easier way to get spell checker working?

Comment: Modern browsers already have spell checkers.

Comment: @Slaks beat me to my original comment, but in addition, if your internal clients running an older version of IT, I'd recommend IESpell over writing one yourself.

Comment: @SLaks Corporate environment... ie 6 - ie8 with a few mobile devices thrown into the mix. I can't rely on the browser or install software on clients. :(

Comment: Is a Javascript-based spellchecker an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what I found out.

TinyMCE has two commands that it uses to perform a spellcheck.
These commands are sent in json format and have the same syntax.

In my usage I have to use a specific phonetic spellcheck routine. So I parse the json request call my spellcheck and then generate a json response.

**POST**
id - string id, generated by tinyMCE
method - either the string "checkWords" or "getSuggestions"
params - an object array, for checkWords it is (<string>, <stringarray>) for getSuggestions it is (<string>, <string>)

**Expected Response**
result - a string array
id - the same id from the post
error - An error message I'm assuming, I always just return null.

**Example usage**

```
Post  
{"id":"c0","method":"checkWords","params":["en",["This","is","a","sentancce","woth","speeling","missteaks"]]}

Expected Response
{"result":["sentancce","woth","speeling","missteaks"],"id":"c0","error":null}

Post
{"id":"c0","method":"getSuggestions","params":["en","sentancce"]}

Expected Response
{"result":["sentence","sentenced","sentences","sentience"],"id":"c0","error":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the spellcheck plugin shipped with tinymce and set up a spellcheck server on a machiene in the intranet. IESpell is a good way to go here.

Comment: have a look here: http://www.kelvinluck.com/2009/01/using-spell-checker-for-tinymce-with-net-on-iis/

Comment: I don't think you read the article `it accepts the AJAX request from a TinyMCE instance, sends it off to Google’s spell checking web service and sends the relevant results back in the AJAX response`

Comment: but this is exactly how the spellcheck plugin of tinymce works

Comment: you do not need to use google spellchecker but you can adress your own IESpell server

Answer (score 0):

I did implement NetSpell to spell check city names. Nothing existed, so I developed a web service in C# that was called from the client which took the string, passed it through NetSpell (with custom dictionaries) and then returned if the city/state combination was good and if not, what suggestions NetSpell gave.

Some AJAX magic displayed a dropdown with the suggestions the web service returned. The whole thing had to be custom though. If you need to spell check things without calling an external web service, I think this is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer by Thariama is close ehough. I've checked out the spell checker sample included in the [TinyMce .NET package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinymce/files/TinyMCE%20.NET%20Package/1.0a2/tinymce_package_dotnet_1_0a2.zip/download), and it looks quite straightforward to hook up a custom spell checker instead of the provided GoogleSpellChecker class. You just have to implement the ISpellChecker interface (two simple methods), switch GoogleSpellChecker to that implementation in the SpellCheckerModule.cs file. For the actual spell checking you could use [NHunspell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhunspell/), a .NET version of the OpenOffice spell checker. For a description on hooking up SpellCheckerModule with TinyMCE see the link provided by Thariama ([kelvinluck.com/2009/01/...](http://www.kelvinluck.com/2009/01/using-spell-checker-for-tinymce-with-net-on-iis/))

Comment: Yeah, that's the part I'm missing. The actual hooking up of tinymce to a custom spellchecker.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses COM. It will work great as long as Microsoft Word is installed.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/spellcheckdemo.aspx